# Does MongoDB offers facilities to transform to other (JSON) formats?

Tags: mongodb, transformation

The task is simple. We will develop a mid-tier layer that will read a JSON feed from somewhere and cache it on MongoDB as is. It will then service this data in a different JSON format.

I'm wondering if MongoDB has built in capabilities to make the transformation itself. If not, the mid-tier will have to do it.

In that case, are there any good tools for the job? Spring Batch can do it but it might be overkill. Also, at this point, the data will be transformed on the fly, unless this causes significant slowdowns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nope - Mongodb is just a data store.  What goes in is what comes out.  If youre just looking to restructure the data, that should be fairly trivial in your app code.

Comment: No problem - if that answered your question, please select it as the answer :)